# Using a parameter with WHERE x IN (a,b,c)

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, ms-access-2010, where-clause

*Using ACCESS 2010

I have a table of events with an EventID,
and a table of guests with a GuestID and an EventID.
(There is a users tavle too)

I want to select all the events of the users in a certain list,
for example: 1, 12, 34, 35;

to do so I will make my WHERE condition like this:

```
WHERE (UsersEventsTbl.UserID In (1, 12, 34, 35));
```

but I encounter a problem when I try to pass this list as an arguemnt like this:

```
WHERE (UsersEventsTbl.UserID In ([@UserIDs]));
```

How else can I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: What does the content of @UserIDs look like?

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is never going to work. You would need to build the string in VBA.

Comment: According to this article, you will need to use VBA... http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=186640

Comment: It is possible with VBA as Wayne mentioned, but for this we need a bit more information as in where is this list populated? How are you intending to launch this query?

Comment: Why not try a nested SELECT. I have never tried it in acccess but something like `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (WHERE (UsersEventsTbl.UserID In (SELECT...)` in that second select you could select the list of userid's that apply to your situation. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

Well if you are already populating your users in a certain list, just populate them in a table rather than in a variable, then inner join that table with your query to filter your users you want... That is the simplest way if you want to avoid unnecessary VBA

Comment: Wouldnt it be a waste of memory to select unnecessary data?

Comment: Actually, in terms of memory, there is no way around it.  even if you use VBA or temporary variables, they all need to be stored somewhere, memory will still be used. The advantage of this approach would be the simplicity of the query and gains in speed